# How to avoid getting search results from files that are in a directory that contains a folder named "xyz" in its path

Tags: vimrc, quickfix, vimgrep

I would like to exclude results of a vimgrep search pattern from the quick fix list. The exclusions should be for all files that are under a directory or parent directory called "xyz".

Example: hello/how/xyz/are/you/ty.c or hello/how/are/xyz/you/ty.c should be excluded in the quick fix list from the search results in quick fix list of a string that is contained in ty.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Cfilter` plugin that comes with vim:

```
:packadd cfilter
:Cfilter! /xyz/
```

(more at `:help cfilter-plugin`)

See `:colder` and `:cnewer` to move between different versions of the quickfix list.

Comment: Why does :Cfilter! /Xyz/ not work when I add it to my vimrc...but works after I vimgrep and enter it as a command in vim, is there any way to make it work from vimrc?

Comment: You can put the packadd in your vimrc, but the commands filter the current quickfix list. So if there is no current qf list, it doesn’t do anything; and, it won’t be applied every time the qf list changes. For that you would need an autocommand and that seems likely to get in the way when you don’t want it.

Comment: I think I'll just create a normal mode map shortcut for this, that would be easier

Answer (score 3):

`:vimgrep` can take multiple file globs. In simple cases that means you can potentially search only places you want instead of excluding (think white-listing vs black-listing)

```
:vimgrep /foo/ bar/** baz/**
```

Often `:vimgrep` isn't up to the task from performance and/or complex searching perspective. Instead you can use Vim's `:grep` command to use an external command like `grep`, `ag`, `rg`, `ack`, or `git-grep` by setting `'grepprg'` and `'grepformat'`.

An example of using [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) to exclude `zxy` and only search in `c` files for pattern, `pat`:

```
$ rg -g '!zyx' -t c 'pat'
```

With a few `vimrc` settings you use `:grep`:

```
:set grepprg=rg\ --vimgrep
:set grepformat^=%f:%l:%c:%m
```

Inside Vim you can now use ripgrep and `:grep` together:

```
:grep -g '!zyx' -t c 'pat'
```

Of course as D. Ben Knoble said above, you can always use `:Cfilter` to filter/exclude from the quickfix after the fact